# return objects instead of promises proto, useEffect()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I'm trying to access data inside a user object stored in firestore, but both console.log(user) will often return `__proto__: object` which is a promise, not the actual object.

```
function StorefrontPage(props) {
  const auth = useAuth();
  const router = useRouter();
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});

  const uid = auth.user && auth.user.uid;


  useEffect(() => {
    uid && getUser(uid).then(currentUser => {
      setUser(currentUser);
    })
    console.log(user);
  }, [])

  console.log(user);
```

The first time I run this, it returns the objects I want, but subsequent refreshes and page changes will turn the console.log into a **proto** object or promise. I thought wrapping it inside of the useEffect hook would solve this issue, but it is not. How do I make sure it always returns the user object instead of a promise?

For reference, the getUser function is:

```
export function getUser(uid) {
  return firestore.collection('users').doc(uid).get().then(user => {
    return user.data();
  })
}
```